# T-SQL / SQL Server : help to calculate turnover time for account to become positve from negative balance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need help to calculate turnover time of any account to become positive from negative daily balance. For example, account 12345 is positive on 04/05/2013, but has negative balance on 04/06, 04/07, 04/08 (three days) and on fourth day it became positive. I would like to develop a query to calculate that turnover time (4 days).

```
Account Number  Transaction Date    Daily Balance
    12345       4/1/2013            304
    12345       4/2/2013            -78
    12345       4/3/2013            -65
    12345       4/4/2013            12
    12345       4/5/2013            25
    12345       4/6/2013            -345
    12345       4/7/2013            -450
    12345       4/8/2013            -650
    12345       4/9/2013            105
    12345       4/10/2013           110
    110000      4/1/2013            150
    110000      4/2/2013            -15
    110000      4/3/2013            -56
    110000      4/4/2013            -35
    110000      4/5/2013            -15
    110000      4/6/2013            106
    110000      4/7/2013            500
    110000      4/8/2013            -150
    110000      4/9/2013            50
    110000      4/10/2013           100
    55544       4/1/2013            150
    55544       4/2/2013            120
    55544       4/3/2013            -145
    55544       4/4/2013            -250
    55544       4/5/2013            15
    55544       4/6/2013            20
    55544       4/7/2013            40
    55544       4/8/2013            50
    55544       4/9/2013            -10
    55544       4/10/2013           60
```

I am trying to get following result from above table. The query will apply to transactions table having thousands of rows. Hence, I need help to build some efficient query to calculate following results.

```
Account Number  Turnover time for an account to become positive
12345           3
12345           4
110000          5
110000          2
55544           3
55544           2
```

I am using MS SQL server version 2008.

Yes there are zeros. and they are consider as positive. I mean when balance is turning from negative to 0 or positive, it will be consider as turnover.

The solution provided by Fadi Hassan is the most efficient and easy to implement. Although there is one challenge with it as when account balance is negative in begining, it doesn't work. For example, when balance is -110, -40, 0, 10, 90, 30, 0, -10, -20, 0. It will not work.

[image]

If somebody have better solution, kindly help.

Comment: Please tag the question with the version of SQL Server

Comment: And how about 0 balances, can there be such ones? When, if at all, should they be counted?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the version is >= SQL Server 2005. There are two things to keep in mind. 1. How is zero account balance treated? 2. The query scans table four times. So its not very efficient.

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT t1.AccountNumber, t1.TransactionDate, t1.DailyBalance, NextRowDailyBalance
FROM #Accounts t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 DailyBalance AS NextRowDailyBalance FROM #Accounts t2 WHERE t1.AccountNumber = t2.AccountNumber AND t1.TransactionDate < t2.TransactionDate ORDER BY t2.TransactionDate)t
WHERE (DailyBalance < 0 AND NextRowDailyBalance>0) OR (DailyBalance > 0 AND NextRowDailyBalance < 0)
)
SELECT a1.AccountNumber, DATEDIFF(Day,a1.TransactionDate,t.NRTransactionDate) + 1 AS TurnOverDate
FROM cte a1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 TransactionDate AS NRTransactionDate FROM cte a2 WHERE a1.AccountNumber = a2.AccountNumber AND a1.TransactionDate < a2.TransactionDate ORDER BY a2.TransactionDate)t
WHERE a1.DailyBalance>0
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were looking for @prem    (edit)

```
    SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  a.[Account Number],
            a.[Transaction Date],
            a.[Daily Balance],
            DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(    (
                        SELECT  MAX(c.[Transaction Date])
                        FROM    Accounts c
                        WHERE   c.[Account Number] = a.[Account Number]
                            AND c.[Transaction Date] < a.[Transaction Date]
                            AND c.[Daily Balance] >= 0
                        ),
                        (
                        SELECT  DATEADD(dd, -1, MIN(c.[Transaction Date]))
                        FROM    Accounts c
                        WHERE c.[Account Number] = a.[Account Number]
                        )
                        ),
            a.[Transaction Date]) AS dat
        FROM    Accounts a
        WHERE a.[Daily Balance] >= 0
    ) t
WHERE   dat > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the most efficient query out of 3, but I am seeing only an issue when account is negative on day one and turn to be positive later on, the query is not considering those turnover. For example, account having -150, -100, 0, 1, 110, -20, -30, 0, 80, 0. The query will not consider for the first turnover as the balance is already negative. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT a.[Account Number],
  a.[Transaction Date],
  a.[Daily Balance],
  DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL
  (
  (SELECT MAX(c.[Transaction Date])
  FROM Accounts c
  WHERE c.[Account Number] = a.[Account Number]
    AND c.[Transaction Date] < a.[Transaction Date]
    AND c.[Daily Balance] >= 0
  )
  ,
  (
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, MIN(c.[Transaction Date]))
  FROM Accounts c
  WHERE c.[Account Number] = a.[Account Number]
  )
  ), a.[Transaction Date]) AS dat
FROM Accounts a
WHERE a.[Daily Balance] >= 0
) t
WHERE dat > 1

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT [Account Number],
                [Transaction Date],
                [Daily Balance],
                MAX([Transaction Date]) 
                          OVER (PARTITION BY [Account Number]) AS FinalAccountTransaction,
                ROW_NUMBER() 
                          OVER (PARTITION BY [Account Number] 
                                    ORDER BY [Transaction Date]) - 
                ROW_NUMBER() 
                          OVER (PARTITION BY [Account Number], 
                                             CASE WHEN [Daily Balance] < 1 THEN 1 END 
                                    ORDER BY [Transaction Date]) AS Grp
         FROM   DailyBalance)
SELECT [Account Number],
       MIN([Transaction Date])                                             AS Start,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN([Transaction Date]), MAX([Transaction Date])) + 2 AS [Turnover time]
FROM   T
WHERE  [Daily Balance] < 1
GROUP  BY [Account Number],
          Grp,
          FinalAccountTransaction
/*If this is the final group then it is not followed by a positive so exclude*/
HAVING MAX([Transaction Date]) <> FinalAccountTransaction
ORDER  BY [Account Number],
          Start
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65379/1)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below solution using cursor, modify column names accordingly.
Hope this helps you

```
-- CREATE temp table with rownum to add row numbers
CREATE TABLE #TurnOverTimeTaken
(
    rownum INT,
    Account_Number INT NULL,
    Daily_Balance INT
)

-- Insert data into the temp table with row number
INSERT INTO #TurnOverTimeTaken
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  Account_Number ORDER BY Account_Number) AS rownum
  ,Account_Number
  ,Daily_Balance
FROM TurnOverTimeTaken

-- Create another temp table to display the result  
CREATE TABLE #Result
(
    Account_Number INT NULL,
    Total INT
)

DECLARE @rownum INT
DECLARE @Account_Number INT
DECLARE @Daily_Balance INT
DECLARE @CurrentVal INT

SET @CurrentVal = 0

--Cursor starts here
DECLARE CountCursor CURSOR 
FOR SELECT rownum, Account_Number, Daily_Balance FROM #TurnOverTimeTaken
OPEN CountCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM CountCursor INTO @rownum, @Account_Number, @Daily_Balance
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    -- Check Daily_Balance is negative and rownumber is not equal to one and previous Daily_Balance > 0
    IF(@Daily_Balance < 0 AND @rownum <> 1 AND 
    (SELECT Daily_Balance FROM #TurnOverTimeTaken WHERE rownum=@rownum-1 AND Account_Number=@Account_Number) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentVal = @CurrentVal + 1
        INSERT INTO #Result VALUES(@Account_Number, @CurrentVal)
    END
    ELSE IF(@Daily_Balance < 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Result VALUES(@Account_Number, @CurrentVal)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM CountCursor INTO @rownum, @Account_Number, @Daily_Balance
END
CLOSE CountCursor
DEALLOCATE CountCursor

--SELECT * FROM #TurnOverTimeTaken

SELECT Account_Number,COUNT(Total)+1 FROM #Result
GROUP BY Account_Number,Total

DROP TABLE #TurnOverTimeTaken
DROP TABLE #Result
```